# JSTL - if condition

Tags: jstl

How to use if in JSTL? I would like do something like this.

```
<c:if  ${order.products} == NULL>
a
else
b
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${order.products == null}">
  a
 </c:when>
 <c:otherwise>
  b
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the syntax is this or something similar.

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${order.products == null}">
a
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
b
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Instead of `<c:if>` it should be `<c:when>`